# Get RTMP uri to Youtube LiveStream video

Tags: youtube, rtmp, youtube-data-api

Can I get RTMP uri of Youtube live-stream using live-stream ID with Youtube Data API v3? For example, for this channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YKR-rEwOr8

When I try to do this using "try" page https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list (part = "status,cdn", id = "4YKR-rEwOr8") I got empty list:

```
200 OK

- Hide headers -

Cache-Control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Length:  183
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Mon, 27 Oct 2014 11:10:54 GMT
Etag:  "PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/HzQflIssFHeC_PS9MZIweemMYZg"
Expires:  Mon, 27 Oct 2014 11:10:54 GMT
Server:  GSE

{
"kind": "youtube#liveStreamListResponse",
"etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/HzQflIssFHeC_PS9MZIweemMYZg\"",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 0,
"resultsPerPage": 0
},
"items": [
]
}
```

What I do wrong? I really don't understand.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?